# How do I stop this error when creating a new Role Provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to add a new Role Provider into my MVC5 project - however on the "return roles.ToArray();" line I get the error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'wb.Models.UserRole[]' to 'string[]'`

```
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        var roles = db.UserRole
                    .Where(x => x.UserName
                    .Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (roles != null)
                return roles.ToArray();
            else
               return new string[] { }; ;
     }
```

Can anyone suggest how I correct this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an array of roles, not role names.  Select out the names and return them as an array.

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    var roleNames = 
        db.UserRole
            .Where(x => x.UserName.Equals(username, 
                StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Select(x => x.RoleName);

    if (roleNames.Count() > 0)
        return roleNames.ToArray();
    else
        return new string[] { }; ;
 }
```

Comment: thank you David - I'll mark as the answer as soon as SO allows. Mark

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is in the following line:

```
roles.ToArray();
```

This returns an array of `wb.Models.UserRole` instead of an array of strings, `string[]`. One option I see, it would be before the call of `ToArray()` to select an anonymous type with one string property, which would contain the information you want. Something like this:

```
 var roles = db.UserRole
               .Where(x => x.UserName
               .Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
               .Select(x => x.RoleName);
```

I am not sure if your class has a property called `RoleName`, but in general terms you should project the results of your query like above, in a sequence of strings. Then calling `ToArray` will create an array of strings and you would be more than done.